# Docker Host And Other Fundamental Questions

Tags: docker, docker-container

I am new to Docker. And have few easy questions hope you could help.

I have a windows 10 machine which installed "docker for windows". In its HyperV manager I could see a virtual machine called "MobyLinuxVM".

So my questions are:

1, **When people talking about "Docker Host" and "Docker Engine", what are they according to my situation**?

-- I assume "Docker Host" should be my windows PC, and "Docker Engine" is that Virtual machine inside Hyper-V.

2, If I use ipconfig to see my PC, I will find I got at lease 2 networks and IP addresses:

```
  (a) Lan Adapter -- show my IP is 192.168.xxx.yyy

  (b) DockerNAT -- show my IP is 10.0.75.1
```

Then when I try to use dock-compose.yml to create container, I found I could ONLY use:

```
environment:

- MAGENTO_HOST=10.0.75.2 

- MARIADB_HOST=10.0.75.2
```

to create container and can be directly accessed (e.g. via browser to Magento website). So question is:

**If my machine is 10.0.75.1 within Docker network, then what is 10.0.75.2? why I cannot use e.g. 10.0.75.3?**

3, My yml script actually contains multiple containers creation -- e.g. 2 Magento containers + 2 MariaDB containers + etc. **When I specify their docker 'HOST', why it's not my machine? (If we call my machine to be 'docker host' & hyper-v virtual image to be 'docker engine' in my 1st question.)**

4, Also according to my 3rd question, I current deploy all containers within 1 host. Is it worth to use **Docker Swarm** which people can use to cluster multiple Docker hosts? If so, does that mean I need to use Hyper-V to create another "MobyLinuxVM"?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

#### 1 Docker Engine + Docker Host

The Docker Engine is the group of processes that manage Docker containers. `dockerd` is usually the head of that process tree.

The Docker Host is the OS running Docker engine, that is MobyLinuxVM

Your VM host is your Windows box.

#### 2 Docker Host IP

10.0.75.2 is most likely the address assigned to MobyLinuxVM. I don't run Docker for Windows so can't entirely confirm but searching the web seems to back this up.

#### 3 - see 1

#### 4 Swarm

You would need to run multiple VMs to setup swarm. [Docker machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/) is the tool to use when setting up swarm instances. It allows you to manage multiple Docker instances and comes with a HyperV driver.

Comment: Hi Matt, have you used Microsoft Azure Container Service? If you have, could you please assist with concept in ACS for my question 1 & 4?

Comment: I've not used Azure's container service either but 1 is not different. Azure will spin up a VM which is the Docker Host that runs the Docker engine as a process. They allow Marathon/Swarm/Kubernetes/DCOS as management options so you have need to use docker-machine to manage the swarm, but you can if you want to.